# Page Not Found Error occured while trying to render form in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I've been following the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs).

This is the error it gives me, when i try to run it on localhost:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:7000/account.html

Using the URLconf defined in gettingstarted.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this   
order:

[name='index']
[name='account']
db/ [name='db']
admin/
^celery-progress/

The current path, account.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change   
that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

This is what i have in my urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
 path("", hello.views.index, name="index"),
 path("", hello.views.account, name="account"),
 path("db/", hello.views.db, name="db"),
 path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
 re_path(r'^celery-progress/', include('celery_progress.urls'))
 ]
```

This is what i have in views.py

```
def account(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AccountForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('loading.html')

else:
    form = Nameform()

return render(request, 'account.html', {'form': form})
```

Finally this is the form itself(account.html):

```
<form action="/account/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have the feeling i'm missing something really simple but i can't for the life of me see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that you tried to access `account.html` directly?

Comment: I've tried to both type in the url and access it from a link in my index.html page. both give the error message described above.

Comment: you don't have `path("account.html", ...)` so it can't find `http://localhost:7000/account.html`. Maybe you forgot `"account.html"` in `path("", hello.views.account, name="account"),`

Comment: BTW: if you use `<form action="/account/` then it will try to connect to `http://localhost:7000/account/` without `.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to change the URL patterns, because ***multiple views (`hello.views.index` and `hello.views.account`) are pointing towards the same pattern***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("index/", hello.views.index, name="index"),
    path("account/", hello.views.account, name="account"),
    path("db/", hello.views.db, name="db"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^celery-progress/', include('celery_progress.urls'))
]
```

then, access the URL, **`http://localhost:7000/account/`**

Comment: i have tried path("account/", hello.views.account, name="account"), so that they are not pointing to the same thing. still same error message.

Comment: Which URL are you accessing?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path("", hello.views.index, name="index"),
    path("account/", hello.views.account, name="account"),
    path("db/", hello.views.db, name="db"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^celery-progress/', include('celery_progress.urls'))
]

Comment: you need to access **`http://localhost:7000/account/`**  (ending with a slash)

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting for the url that could match the string `/account/` but in your `urlpatterns` variable you have an empty string so it can't match anything.

Remember that the first argument of `urlpatterns` is a pattern string that can be matched with regex.

Perhaps you could map it like:

```
path("/account/", hello.views.account, name="account")
```